# JSON deserialisation failing (HTTP 400) with Jersey / MOXy

Tags: java, json, jersey, moxy

I have a relatively simple RESTful web service which uses Jersey and Eclipselink MOXy.

I can POST requests to the service if the data is formatted as XML, but if I send it as JSON instead, the server generates an HTTP 400 (Bad Request), with the message: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.".

The service-side looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Subscription post(Subscription Subscription) {
    return Subscriptions.addSubscription(Subscription);
}
```

If I send it XML data from Javascript in a webpage like this, there is no problem:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyService/subscription',
type: 'POST',
    data:  "<subscription><notificationType>EMAIL</notificationType><notificationAddress>test@example.com</notificationAddress></subscription>",
    headers: { 
            Accept : "application/xml",
            "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    },
     // .. other params ... 
 );
```

However, with the equivalent JSON I get HTTP 400 - Bad Request:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyService/subscription',
type: 'POST',
    data:  JSON.stringify(
                {subscription:{notificationType:"EMAIL",notificationAddress:"test@example.com"}}
            ),
    dataType: 'json'
    headers: { 
            Accept : "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
     }
     // .. other params ... 
 );
```

I have inspected the request using Fiddler, and the data formatting and headers all look correct.

The interesting thing is that I can successfully unmarshall the exact same JSON string if I plug it into this code:

```
String json = "{\"subscription\":{\"notificationType\":\"EMAIL\",\"notificationAddress\":\"test@example.com\"}}";
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Subscription.class);
Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();
m.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(json);
Subscription sub = (Subscription)m.unmarshal(sr);
System.out.println(sub.toString());
```

The subscription class is defined as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="subscription")
public class Subscription {

    public enum NotificationType { EMAIL, SMS };

    private String notificationAddress;

    private NotificationType notificationType;

    public String getNotificationAddress() {
        return notificationAddress;
    }

    public void setNotificationAddress(String notificationAddress) {
        this.notificationAddress = notificationAddress;
    }
    public NotificationType getNotificationType() {
        return notificationType;
    }

    public void setNotificationType(NotificationType notificationType) {
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
    }
    public Subscription() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Subscription";
        if (getNotificationAddress() != null) {
            s += "(" + getNotificationType().toString() + ":" + getNotificationAddress() + ")";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

I have configured Eclipselink MOXy as my JAXB provider by adding this line to jaxb.properties in the package that contains my Subscriber class:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

and that seems to work, at least for marshalling objects going out from the service.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:
This is what Fiddler captures when I post the JSON data:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/MyService/subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 86
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/TestPage/AddSubscription.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

{"subscription":{"notificationType":"EMAIL","notificationAddress":"test@example.com"}}
```

**UPDATE:**

I took Option#2 from Blaise's answer below, created an Application-derived class, thus:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class MyApplication  extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(SubscriptionResource.class); // the class containing my @POST service method.
        return set;
    }
 }
```

And added to web.xml:

```
   <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
   <param-value>com.example.MyApplication</param-value>
```

And now I don't get an HTTP 400, and the code in my service is hit, which it wasn't before, however the passed-in Subscription object has all uninitialized fields, e.g. notificationAddress is null.
If I post using XML, it still works ok.

**UPDATE#2:**

I have reduced my code to the smallest subset that demonstrates the problem, and you can get it here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2a6iqw65ey0ahrk/D2ILi_722z

The above link contains a .zip with 2 Eclipse projects;  TestService (the Jersey RESTful service that accepts a Subscription object) and TestPage (a .html page with some JavaScript to POST a subscription object in either JSON or XML).

If you put a breakpoint in the post method of the service, and use the test page to send the JSON request, you'll see an un-initialised Subscription object gets passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) can be used with Jersey in a couple of different ways to produce JSON.

**Option #1 - Add a jaxb.properties File**

Jersey can leverage a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation to produced JSON.  If you add a `jaxb.properties` in with your domain model then you can specify MOXy as that provider.  For a while the following bug existed in Jersey that prevented MOXy from being used in this way which may be what you are hitting now.

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-753

This method of producing JSON has some limitations and may not be what your ultimately want.

**Option #2 - Leverage `MOXyJsonProvider`**

As of EclipseLink 2.4.0 MOXy offers its own JSON-binding based on the JAXB and MOXy metadata.  You can configure this using the MOXyJsonProvider.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class MyApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(1);
        set.add(SubscriptionResource.class);
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
        moxyJsonProvider.setIncludeRoot(true);

        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(1);
        set.add(moxyJsonProvider);
        return set;
    }

}
```

For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

This is the way I would recommend using MOXy with Jersey, or any other JAX-RS provider.

Comment: @DaveW - Since your JSON message has a root node you will need to tell `MOXyJsonProvider` to include the root.  I have updated my answer with an example `Application` class.

Comment: Awesome! That seemed to do the trick. (Thanks for all your help in this and other questions - it's much appreciated).